# How do I force Python to append to a csv file that someone currently has open?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv

Is there a way to do this? Here is my current code.

```
try:
    if len(df) > 0:
        with open(r'\\path\to\dir\IDS_' + str(now)[:-2] + '.csv', 'a') as f:
            df.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=False, index=True, encoding='utf-8')
            f.close()
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Comment: You don't need `f.close()`, this is what the `with` statement is for.

Comment: I don't t think you can append in a file if someone is using it. You can do a copy and append to the copy.

Comment: What operating system are you on? What error are you getting? Please give steps to reproduce your issue

Comment: Is it just a pseduo code? It seems doable. Try it out and update the post if you face any issue

Comment: I always do f.close() because, for whatever reason, sometimes it doesn't close the document. This is not pseudo code. I am on a Windows 10 operating system.

Comment: @NickTheInventor no, it *will always close the document if you use a `with` statement*. That is the *entire point of using the `with` statement here* If you are seriously seeing that behavior you should file a bug report ASAP

Comment: You can't append to a `.csv` if you or someone else has it open in Excel. You can't even *read* it if you or someone else has it open in Excel. You can't force Python to do this because it is not Python that is preventing it. Excel opens files with an exclusive lock and if Python tries to access the file, Windows will prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can't edit a file that someone already has open. What I can do is handle the Exceptione by using cPickle to dump the new information into a pickle file and load it when it's time to put the file into the csv the next time around.

```
try:
    if len(df) > 0:
        with open(r'\\path\to\dir\IDS_' + str(now)[:-2] + '.csv', 'a') as f:
            df.to_csv(f, sep=',', header=False, index=True, encoding='utf-8')
            f.close()
except Exception, e:
   cPickle.dump(df, open(r'C:\missed rows.p','wb'))

missed_rows = cPickle.load(open(r'C:\missed rows.p','rb'))

if len(missed_rows) > 0:
    df = missed_rows.append(df, sort=True)
    missed_rows = pd.DataFrame()
    cPickle.dump(missed_rows, open(r'C:\missed rows.p','wb'))
    df = df.drop_duplicates()
```